# Would "answerable to my department" be correct

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence

I had assigned some work to one of the staff in my department which has been delayed and I have to write an email asking her to speed things up.

Would this be correct?

> Please make this quick as I am answerable to the people in my
>   department.

Comment: [Definition of ***answerable:***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/answerable) **1:** *liable to be called to account* (cf ***responsible***)

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers so it should be okay, right?

Comment: Yeah - your example text is fine. But in case you don't realise, I would just say that ***make it quick*** is a fairly informal / colloquial usage, whereas ***to be answerable** [to some authority]* is a rather formal / high-falutin' usage. That could be seen as "natural with a touch of whimsy" in your context, since you're effectively implying something like *Me and you are mates, so we can interact fairly casually, but the people I work for / with in my department expect me to deal with things promptly and professionally.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would go with *held accountable* instead, as in:

> Please make this quick as I will be **held accountable** to the people in my department.

From the Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> ***[accountable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/accountable)***
>
> **adjective**
>
> 1. Required or expected to justify actions or decisions; responsible.
>
>    *‘ministers are accountable to Parliament’*
>    *‘parents cannot be held accountable for their children's actions’*

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I'm a little late with this comment but I'm curious to know if 'held accountable *by* the people..' would be wrong and how it change the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: _held accountable **by** the people_ would be perfectly fine and might even be preferable.  The difference is that when you say you're _accountable to_, you're highlighting your responsibility to those people.  If you say you're _held accountable by_, you're highlighting their interest in what you do.  Consider a child who says _I won't take the cookie because I don't want to make mommy sad_ versus one who says _mommy told me not to take the cookie so I won't._  The first is analogous to _accountable to_ whereas the second is more like _held accountable by_.